# Regex match a subgroup which ends with a "/"

Tags: javascript, regex

I have two urls and need to capture a string after domain extension, if it's a two character string and it ends with a "/". So far I've got this:

```
var t1 = "http://www.test.net/shop/test-3";
var t2 = "http://www.test.net/gb/shop/test-2";

var rgx = /\.([a-z]{0,3})\/([a-z]{2}\/)?/;



console.log(rgx.exec(t1));

console.log(rgx.exec(t2));
```

It spits out

```
[".net/", "net", undefined]
[".net/gb/", "net", "gb/"]
```

which is correct, except I don't want to capture "gb/", but "gb" instead. Any ideas? I'm quite stuck..

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can simply use the forward slash as a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead) which will not put it in the capture group like so `(?=\/)`

As [Evaldas Raisutis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1905962/evaldas-raisutis) mentioned in a comment, this will not match the two characters if the two characters are the *last* thing in the URL and there is no trailing slash, so instead `(?=\/|$)` can be used which will match a `/` *or* the end of the line thus making that part optional. Which transforms your pattern into

```
\.([a-z]{0,3})\/([a-z]{2}(?=\/|$))?
```

[See in Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/jI9aK2/2)

```js
var t1 = "http://www.test.net/shop/test-3";
var t2 = "http://www.test.net/gb/shop/test-2";
var t3 = "http://www.test.net/de/";
var t4 = "http://www.test.net/fr";

var rgx = /\.([a-z]{0,3})\/([a-z]{2}(?=\/|$))?/;

console.log(rgx.exec(t1));
console.log(rgx.exec(t2));
console.log(rgx.exec(t3));
console.log(rgx.exec(t4));
```

Comment: Not sure why the down votes, but I ended up with this. Except it turned out I also needed to make trailing slash optional, so finished with /\.([a-z]{0,3})\/([a-z]{2}(?=\/|$))?/

Comment: @EvaldasRaisutis yes, if you do have other after the two character code, the above regex would have worked, but not if it's the last thing in the URL. I'll just add this to the answer for better visibility.

Answer (score 6):

A technique you can use is using the capturing group inside an optional non-capturing group:

```
/\.([a-z]{0,3})\/(?:([a-z]{2})\/)?/
                 ^^^^           ^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lM0bW7/2)

```js
var t1 = "http://www.test.net/shop/test-3";
var t2 = "http://www.test.net/gb/shop/test-2";
console.log(/\.([a-z]+)\/(?:([a-z]{2})\/)?/.exec(t1));
console.log(/\.([a-z]+)\/(?:([a-z]{2})\/)?/.exec(t2));
```

Speaking about alternative approaches, this regex seems safer as it is more precise:

```
/^https?:\/\/[^\/]+\.([a-z]+)\/(?:([a-z]{2})\/)?/
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jK6yO1/3)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `https?:\/\/` - a protocal part (`http://` or `https://`)
- `[^\/]+\.([a-z]+)\/` - the domain part matching one or more chars other than `/` then `.` and then capturing the TLD (1 or more letters, `[a-z]+`) into Group 1
- `(?:([a-z]{2})\/)?` - an optional sequence of:

  - `([a-z]{2})` - Group 2 capturing 2 lowercase ASCII letters
  - `\/` - a slash.

```js
var t1 = "http://www.test.net/shop/test-3";
var t2 = "http://www.test.net/gb/shop/test-2";
console.log(/^https?:\/\/[^\/]+\.([a-z]+)\/(?:([a-z]{2})\/)?/.exec(t1));
console.log(/^https?:\/\/[^\/]+\.([a-z]+)\/(?:([a-z]{2})\/)?/.exec(t2));
```

Comment: I agree with looking for the first `/` and going from there. It's indeed way more precise. One thing I'd just note is that the domain name could have more than three characters (`domain.info`), so I'd remove that limitation. Assuming a URL is being parsed (as opposed to free text), then we only really want everything between the last `.` and before the first `/`. That is _if_ the TLD is even relevant - if it's not, then simply getting everything after the first and second `/` is enough. Though it might be even easier without using regex.

Comment: @vlaz: Thank you for a valuable comment, I updated the answer. There can be other enhancements here, too, I just do not know if OP needs them here :)

Comment: True, depending on the use case, it might be an overkill.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach would be to parse the *first* element after the domain extension out of the string:

```js
function parse(str){
    // Remove the domain extension and everything before that.
    // Then return the first section of the rest, before `/`
    return str.replace(/.+\.\w+\//, '')
              .split('/')[0];
}
console.log(parse("http://www.test.net/shop/test-3"));
console.log(parse("http://www.test.net/gb/shop/test-2"));
console.log(parse("http://www.test.net/nl"));
```

This way, you can easily check the length of the returned results.

Regex explanation:

```
.+\.\w+\/
.+  - matches any character (except newline)
          Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
\.  - matches the character . literally
\w+ - match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]
          Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
\/  - matches the character / literally
```

This regex basically grabs everything before the domain extension, the domain extension itself, and the `/` behind it.